# PHP BITRIX работа с корзиной

Tags: php, битрикс, корзина

[image: Поле корзины][image: Вывод суммы]
Нужно, чтобы в поле сумма выводилась сумма заказов из корзины

---

Каким образом это осуществить

Comment: Для того чтобы ответить на такой вопрос необходимо видеть пример кода, подсчитывающего и выводящего сумму. Если ответить быстро, то ответ будет такой: "Используйте тот же код, что и для подсчета "Итого""

Comment: Уже разобрался с задачей